# ComboBox does not show default text "Select"

Tags: wpf, silverlight

I am new to wpf. This is the code which i am using to bind combo box.but this "select task" is not showing in the combo box.

```
<ComboBox
    IsReadOnly="True"
    IsEditable="True"
    x:Name="combo"
    SelectedIndex="0"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Books}"
    DisplayMemberPath="Value"
    SelectedValuePath="Key"
    SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SelectedId, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    Width="120"
    Height="30"
    Margin="5">
    <ComboBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Value="{x:Null}" Binding="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=combo}">
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="Select Task"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.Style>
</ComboBox>
```

Itemsource bind dynamically combo box on selection of something. i need to display "Select Task" always as first element in the combo box but user can select other options and selected option will show up.when there is no options available the only Select Task will show up. please help.

Comment: selected index 0 ? why ?

Comment: What is the behavior if you just set the text statically? Like so <ComboBox Text="Select Task" ...

Answer (score -2):

In Book collection at index 0 , put "Select". that's it

Comment: thats like asking problems to take a break and come back later